# TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame link_left_wheel at time 618.268000 according to authority unknown_publisher

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when ever i start my navigation stack i get this error

```
    Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame link_left_wheel at time 618.268000 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame link_right_wheel at time 618.268000 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1620280861.746819185, 618.270000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame link_left_wheel at time 618.268000 according to authority unknown_publisher
[ WARN] [1620280861.747013021, 618.270000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame link_right_wheel at time 618.268000 according to authority unknown_publisher
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377796/tf_repeated_data-ignoring-data-with-redundant-timestamp-for-frame-link_left_wheel-at-time-618.268000-according-to-authority-unknown_publisher/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgarciav](https://answers.ros.org/users/72940/sgarciav/) on 2021-05-22**:
Have you been able to track down why you are getting this warning message?

**Comment by [Kaveh_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/101393/kaveh_ros/) on 2022-09-15**:
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The warning message is due to a change in transform-handling behavior. In short, it used to be the case that a redundant transform (one with the same timestamp and frame_ids as a previously received transform) would be added to the transform cache alongside the original one. This was apparently not intended behavior, and as of noetic redundant transforms are ignored and a warning is printed (see this [issue](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/414) for more details).
You are definitely not the only one to encounter this, as evidenced by this [discussion](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467).
It's up to you whether to try to hunt down the source of the redundant transforms in your setup and fix it or to just ignore the warnings.

---

Originally posted by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) with karma: 188 on 2021-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was caused by robot_state_publisher (default rate: 50 Hz) publishing at a higher rate than joint_state_publisher (default rate: 10 Hz). So basically the robot_state_publisher was publishing 5 times every joint state with the same time stamp.

The solution was to specify a frequency for both nodes manually in the launch file:

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" >
    <param name="publish_frequency" value="10"/>
</node>
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
    <param name="rate" value="10"/>
</node>
```